# Magento2.4 rest api for get all products inventory

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4, inventory

I need to get all products detail such as inventory, max, min, qty and more. how can I get them with rest api for magento 2.4? I can get it for 1 sku but I need all skus

Answer (score 0):

```
/rest/V1/stockItems/lowStock?scopeId=0&qty=1000&pageSize=5000
```

Finally I can help myself by this API